# Add values from columns into a new column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
id    category    value
1       1          abc
2       2          abc
3       1          abc
4       4          abc
5       4          abc
6       3          abc
```

Category `1 = best`, `2 = good`, `3 = bad`, `4 =ugly`

I want to create a new column such that, for category 1 the value in the column should be `cat_1`, for category 2, the value should be `cat2`.

in new_col2 for category 1 should be `cat_best`, for category 2, the value should be `cat_good`.

```
df['new_col'] = ''
```

my final df

```
id    category    value   new_col   new_col2
1       1          abc     cat_1     cat_best
2       2          abc     cat_2     cat_good
3       1          abc     cat_1     cat_best
4       4          abc     cat_4     cat_ugly
5       4          abc     cat_4     cat_ugly
6       3          abc     cat_3     cat_bad
```

I can iterate it in for loop:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[df.id == row.id,'new_col'] = 'cat_'+str(row['category'])
```

Is there a better way of doing it (least time consuming)

Comment: @Zero The second part of my que is not a duplicate, i suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need join string with column converted to string and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with join for second column:

```
d = {1:'best', 2: 'good', 3 : 'bad', 4 :'ugly'}
df['new_col'] = 'cat_'+ df['category'].astype(str)
df['new_col2'] = 'cat_'+ df['category'].map(d)
```

Or:

```
df = df.assign(new_col= 'cat_'+ df['category'].astype(str), 
               new_col2='cat_'+ df['category'].map(d))

print (df)
   id  category value new_col  new_col2
0   1         1   abc   cat_1  cat_best
1   2         2   abc   cat_2  cat_good
2   3         1   abc   cat_1  cat_best
3   4         4   abc   cat_4  cat_ugly
4   5         4   abc   cat_4  cat_ugly
5   6         3   abc   cat_3   cat_bad
```

Comment: I have added one more column in my output (edit). If category = 1, its best, so the value in new_col2 should be cat_best , n so on

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using apply also:

```
df['new_col']=df['category'].apply(lambda x: "cat_"+str(x))
```